# Make reach UI Menu Button avoid edges of a scrollable element

Tags: reactjs

I have a [Reach UI menu button](https://reach.tech/menu-button/) inside an element with `overflow-y: scroll`. The menu already avoids the edges of the window, but I'd like it to apply the same behavior to the sides (specifically top and bottom) of the scrollable element. I know that the solution probably involves passing a function to the [`position`](https://reach.tech/menu-button/#menupopover-position), function, but i'm not sure what that should look like.

I've created a code sandbox with a fairly minimal setup to illustrate the issue. Each of the buttons shows a menu. Try scrolling while the menu is open.

https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-burnell-u4fjc

Comment: Can you share your elements?

Comment: I've created a codesandbox to illustrate the issue (also added to the question) https://codesandbox.io/s/angry-burnell-u4fjc

Comment: I don't think you saved your codesandbox, I can't see the buttons or the menu.